# Problems with stopping file system filter drivers

Tags: windows, driver, minifilter

I have developed a simple filter driver.

The driver works fine.

I then used the "SC STOP" command to unload the driver.

But this did not work well and I had to use the "FLTMC UNLOAD" command.

I will add several features to my driver.

The "FLTMC UNLOAD" command seems a bit strange to stop all of the driver's functions. (I think)

I want to stop the driver with the "SC STOP" command.

Is this possible?

---

### Below is a modified question.

I am now using OSRLoader to load and unload the driver.

However, when I first developed a filter driver, it did not load the filter driver in a way that loaded the legacy driver.

An error occurred in FltRegisterFilter().

I think my code was not wrong.

But it did not load, I changed the driver type to MiniFilter and it worked fine.

I think it's the difference between the FLTMC command and the SC command.

Why does not FltRegisterFilter() work on legacy drivers?

Comment: `But this did not work well` - How can you so ask questions ?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is.  The `sc` command is used for starting and stopping *Windows services.*  `fltmc` is for loading and unloading *filter drivers*.  You have developed a filter driver.  Hence, `fltmc` seems the right tool... what am I missing?

Comment: @selbie, certain sorts of drivers can be started and stopped with `sc` because drivers and services share some of the same infrastructure.  I don't think that is true for file system filter drivers, but I couldn't say for certain.

Comment: Well ... that's right ... I just want to use the SC command for the file system filter driver.
I will change my question.
I am now using OSRLoader to load and unload the driver.
However, when I first developed a filter driver, it did not load the filter driver in a way that loaded the legacy driver.
An error occurred in FltRegisterFilter().
I think my code was not wrong.
But it did not load, I changed the driver type to MiniFilter and it worked fine.
I think it's the difference between the FLTMC command and the SC command.
Why does not FltRegisterFilter() work on legacy drivers?

Comment: `An error occurred in ` - if error occurred - write what exactly is error, error code. are this so hard understand and do ? *sc* work with minifilters too - it ask *services.exe* and it call *ZwUnloadDriver* . *fltmc* call *FilterUnload* which finally call *FltpDoUnloadFilter* which also call *ZwUnloadDriver*

Comment: FltRegisterFilter return 0xC0000034
STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND

Comment: I think I got the wrong question. Thank you for your attention. I think I need to study more.

Answer (score 0):

FltRegisterFilter is a function that is specific to mini-filters. All the Flt* APIs are part of the Filter Manager, which was introduced in Windows 2000 SP5 plus roll-up pack, IIRC. It does not work on legacy filters because it's not supposed to - by design.

`fltmc unload <driver>` is the preferred way to unload mini-filters because it gives your filter a chance to refuse to unload in it's unload callback. This can be useful if you're writing a driver that can be unloaded, but only if it's not currently filtering something. `sc stop` doesn't allow you this flexibility.